# Using column data from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with one column and that has a list of my company names and what I want to do is be able to create a stats worksheet where I can use those company names without changing both worksheets when a new company is added.

e.g.

Worksheet "Company Names"

```
+ Company Name +
  Company 1
  Company 2
  Company 3
```

Worksheet "stats" with Company Name taken from "Company Name" worksheet

```
+ Company Name + Stat 1 + Stat 2 +
  Company 1        0        12
  Company 2        11       3
  Company 3        4        7
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you want to achieve, I couldn't catch it? :) And where is this "column data from another WS", how does it look?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the correct terminology. What I want to do is to copy one column to another worksheet but not as a 'copy&paste'. I want to be able to update the first worksheet so that the other one updates with the changes e.g. if I changed 'Company 1'to 'Company 234' it would change on both worksheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is to copy one column to another worksheet but not as a 'copy&paste'. I want to be able to update the first worksheet so that the other one updates with the changes e.g. if I changed 'Company 1@ to 'Company 234' it would change on both worksheets

Oh, I see! You are speaking of so-called "link" aren't you?

Try this simple formula like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331469/how-can-i-link-cells-between-two-sheets-so-that-value-gets-updated-on-the-second) `=Sheet1!A1` where Sheet1 is this "another worksheet" and A1 the first cell on it. In right bottom corner of the cell a black cross will appear. With left mouse click grab it and pull down. This will extend your formula down.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Didn't know it was so simple